# No cold water in downstairs bathroom

Tags: plumbing

I have a bathroom in the basement, last night my son flushed the toilet and there was a huge rumbling in the pipes... turned the water off and back on slowly and no more rumbling... however, since then there is no cold water in the sink and the toilet tank does not refill... the rest of the house is fine... I tried opening the cold and blocking the spout and opening the hot... water went into the toilet tank but then stopped as soon as I turned off the hot... is there something else I can try??

Comment: We tried blocking the spout again as well as the inlet in the toilet tank... could hear the water going someplace, couldn't determine where, but did not resolve the issue... any suggestions would be appreciated...

Comment: The valve your son turned off may have broken and is still closed. If it an older valve that is probably what happened. Depending on the type, age manufacturer, construction, etc. the valve may be fixable or may need to be replaced. You may need professional help.